# Proving that the quadratic equation $(q-5)x^2 +5x -q=0$ has real roots for any value of $q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

Prove that the quadratic equation $(q-5)x^2 +5x -q=0$ has real roots for any value of $q$.

So I have already tried using the discriminant but just wanted to see if my answer is right or not. Appreciate every feedback.

Comment: What is your answer and how did you find it? What is the discriminant, and have you shown it is always non-negative?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Obviously $x=1$ is a root. Q.E.D

Comment: To be pedantic, for $q=5$ it has a single real root, not "real roots", but maybe that case is excluded because we are told it is a quadratic equation. But @Huang is still the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Discriminant = {\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}$$
$$ = {\sqrt {5^2-4(-q)(q-5)}}$$
$$ = {\sqrt {25+4(q)(q-5)}}$$
$$ = {\sqrt {4q^2-20q+25}}$$
$$ = {\sqrt {(2q-5)^2}}$$

As ${(2q-5)^2}$  ${\ge}\,0$, real roots always exist.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, and supplementing the discriminant solution offered previously:
$$(q-5)x^2 +5x -q \:=\: (x-1)\big((q-5)x+q\big)$$